# 2 Excel VBA Macros: One to move data from master sheet into separate sheets, another to move updated data from separate sheets into master sheets

Tags: vba, excel

To give some context to the issue, I am trying to create a centralised master question and answer worksheet, which I will then allocate questions to different people. The spreadsheet that is given to people would only show the questions that are allocated to them.

For example, this would be the initial master spreadsheet with questions unanswered.

```
# Allocation Question Answer
1 A          ABC
2 A          DEF
3 B          GHI
4 A          JKL
5 C          MNO
6 B          PQR
```

But person A would only receive the following, and fill in the answer column before sending it back for consolidation to the master sheet.

```
# Allocation Question Answer
1 A          ABC
2 A          DEF
4 A          JKL
```

As the title suggests, I am having some difficulty trying to create a macro to do the following:

- Copy the entire table as values into separate tabs for each designated answered (i.e. a tab called A with just the second table above, and then the same for tab B and tab C, etc.)
- Once the designated answer has then populated their own sheets, they will send it back, and would then need a macro to populate the master sheet, with the answers now filled in

Appreciate this seems like a lot but would be good to know if anyone has done something like this before and could help out if so?

Thanks alot in advance.

AT.

Comment: Post the code you have tried thusfar

Comment: Admittedly I haven't been able to get anything working together as I'm very new to VBA...

Comment: Which version of [tag:google-spreadsheet] supports [tag:vba]?

Comment: Check out [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wBJDyXp2CU) on how to generate a test paper from a question bank.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MoveMasterData()

'Check each date
For Each Allocation In Worksheets("Master").Columns(2).Cells    'Change Master to your sheet name
    If Allocation.Value = "" Then Exit Sub 'Stop program if no data

    If Allocation.Row > 1 Then
        shtName = Allocation.Value    'Assign sheet name

        On Error GoTo errorhandler  'if no allocation Sheet, go to errorhandler to create new tab
        If Worksheets(shtName).Range("A2").Value = "" Then
           Allocation.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(shtName).Range("A2")
           Worksheets(shtName).Range("A1:D1").Columns.AutoFit
        Else
            Allocation.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(shtName).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
        End If
    End If
Next

Exit Sub
errorhandler:
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Create new tab
ActiveSheet.Name = shtName  'Name tab with Allocation
Worksheets("Master").Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Rows(1) 'Copy heading to new tab
Resume

End Sub

Sub CompileMaster()

'Check each Allocation
For Each Allocation In Worksheets("Master").Columns(2).Cells    'Change Master to your sheet name
    If Allocation.Value = "" Then Exit Sub 'Stop program if no data

    If Allocation.Row > 1 Then
        For Each sht In Worksheets
            If Allocation.Value = sht.Name Then
                For Each QNo In sht.Columns(1).Cells
                    If QNo.Value = "" Then Exit For 'Stop program if no data

                    RowQ = WorksheetFunction.Match(QNo, Worksheets("Master").Columns(1), 0) 'Check & Assign Question No
                    Worksheets("Master").Range("D" & RowQ).Value = QNo.Offset(0, 3).Value   'Transfer answer to master
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

End Sub
```